# With regards to Sylow's theorems, why are prime numbers so special in finite groups?

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers, finite-groups

I have recently been introduced to Sylow's theorem. I can't help but think how prime numbers are intimately related to group structure. For example, the fact that a power of a prime number being a divisor of the group's order necessitates the group have a subgroup of the same order is amazing and powerful.

What is it about prime numbers that makes it so? Is there something deeper that I am clearly missing about this apparent connection that prime numbers have with groups?

Comment: I would think that understanding the proof would reveal some of the depth which you crave. Have you grappled with the proof?

Comment: Maybe studying $p$-groups helps

Comment: You may enjoy looking up [Hall subgroups](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_subgroup)

Comment: Prime numbers are just a useful tool. Sylow's theorem is beautiful in its simplicity, but other tools are also useful (as is often the case in maths). Character theory is area of study where linear algebra is used to study groups. It's very hard to study infinite groups without bringing in geometry and graph theory.